# printing results of equation to table

Tags: r

**Edit:**

I am trying to use a function on every combination of values in a vector and save the result to a n x n matrix. My description below is not nearly as concise. Thanks @Deleet

I am trying to print the results of a function to a table, rather then as a list. Can someone explain how to do this **in general**? I included my specific case below.

```
df<-data.frame(
    c1=c(1,2,3),
    c2=c(6,6,6),
    c3=c(23,44,66)
)

temp<-NULL
for(i in colnames(df)){
    for(j in colnames(df)){
        temp<-c(temp,paste0("function(i,j)_RESULT_HERE_FROM FUNCTION"))
    }
}
```

goal:

```
    c1           c2           c3
c1  RESULT_HERE  RESULT_HERE  RESULT_HERE
c2  RESULT_HERE  RESULT_HERE  RESULT_HERE
c3  RESULT_HERE  RESULT_HERE  RESULT_HERE
```

Comment: Could you edit this to be more clear? The first few lines make it seem that you want to use the input values from a 3x3 matrix to a function, otherwise, why write the values there?

But later it seems that you want to use a function on every combination of values in a vector and save the result to a n x n matrix. `outer()` is does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `outer`

```
temp <- outer(colnames(df), colnames(df), 
         FUN=function(x,y) paste0(y, "!!", x, "!!", "RESULT_HERE"))
```

Comment: I believe my post was unclear. I have edited it to try to show that I need to take in a row and column name and output the result of a function

Comment: @Rilcon42 I think you are looking for `outer`, specify the function in the `FUN` but your edit "function(i,j)_RESULT_HERE_FROM FUNCTION" is not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the comment before submitting the edits. Basically I need to take in a row and column name, and return a number. Once I return the number I need to store it in a dataframe

Comment: @Rilcon42 If you are taking a row and column name, why you are only looping the i and j with only column name?  Also, please consider to provide a reproducible example as the expected output and your function is not making reproducible.

Comment: I will have a better (reproducible) example up in just a minute

Comment: In my case the row and column names are identical, so I shortened my code by only using one.....which is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer solved my problem perfectly, despite my poor example. Thanks!

Comment: @Rilcon42 `outer` is a convenient function for these cases.